# How can I express the ration of double factorials $\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}$ as a single factorial?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

How can I change the  double factorial of $$\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$ to single factorial?

Comment: See under [relation to factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2n+1)!!=(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3) \cdots (3) (1)$$

$$=\frac{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4) \cdots (4)(3)(2) (1)}{(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4) \cdots (4)(2)}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4) \cdots (4)(3)(2) (1)}{(2)(n)(2)(n-1)(2)(n-2) \cdots (2)(2)(2)(1)}$$

$$=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(2^n)n!}$$

Similarly,

$$(2n)!!=(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4) \cdots (4)(2)=(2)(n)(2)(n-1)(2)(n-2) \cdots (2)(2)(2)(1)=(2^n)n!$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: $(2n+1)!! = \frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n)!!}$

Hint 2: $(2n)!! = n! 2^n $.